# Exit code 127 when running Docker command inside Process Builder

Tags: java, docker, process

When I try to run basic docker command inside a processBuilder, the exit code is always 127. According to the doc this mean that the command cannot be found, but when I run it inside my terminal everything is running fine.

```
processBuilder.command("bash", "-c", "docker run hello-world");
```

This will not work

```
$ docker run hello-world
```

But this will

I'm running everything on Linux Mint 20

Comment: Those are not the same commands, what output does `bash -c "docker run hello-world"` give when you run it manually?

Comment: It's strange because when I run it mannualy i'm getting the same output as docker run hello-world :/